# Export PhpStorm's settings from installation folder

Tags: phpstorm

Long story short: I can access the files and folder in my hard drive but can't boot into Windows. That really doesn't matter to me, but I want to recover all the live templates and personalized macros within PhpStorm but I didn't export them when I had the chance.

Can I retrieve them from the files/folder?

Comment: All IDE-wide settings are stored in config files. You can just copy them over -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Answer (score 0):

As @LazyOne pointed out, I just had to copy som file from c:\Users\My User.PhpStorm2016.1\